# Config Variables Initialization | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I found interesting the way [Python's requests](https://docs.python-requests.org) library does the `status_code` data structure initialization (see [code here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/aae78010e987a414c176bddbf474cd554505219c/requests/status_codes.py#L107)). I am reusing it in a hobby project, but instead of using just one configuration variable I want it to initialize a few of them, code below:

```
from .models import LookupDict


# Copying Requests data structure and some refactor to data initialization

network_types = LookupDict(name='network_types')
_network_types = {
    1: ('GSM',),
    2: ('UMTS',),
    3: ('LTE',)
}


def _fill(_globals_var, globals_var):
    for value, titles in _globals_var.items():
        for title in titles:
            setattr(globals_var, title, value)


def _init():
    for _globals_var, globals_var in [
        (_network_types, network_types)
    ]:
        _fill(_globals_var, globals_var)


_init()
```

So far it's just defined `network_types` variable but it could initialize as many as you want with both functions `_init` and `_fill`.

`LookupDict` is pretty much the same as the `requests` implementation (see [code here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/aae78010e987a414c176bddbf474cd554505219c/requests/structures.py#L89))

Any comments would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no usage shown, no implementation for `LookupDict` shown and nothing other than your network type values, this is overdesigned and offers nothing beyond

```
class NetworkType(Enum):
    GSM = 1
    UMTS = 2
    LTE = 3
```

Comment: I agree with you it is overdesigned if I won't use the purpose this was originally designed for by `requests`, but I just hate to write this, following your example: `NetworkType.GSM.value` every time I will use any of the config values

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `NetworkType.GSM`? That seems pretty straightforward and readable. The value isn't important in enums, so if your use case is to actually use it, just omit the `(Enum)` from the class.

Comment: I actually need the value, thanks for the last tip, I didn't think about it that way

Comment: PS: LookupDict definition is in the last link